# Showing $ \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z \ncong \mathbb Z/n^2 \mathbb Z $ as $\mathbb Z/n^2\mathbb Z$-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I'm trying to disprove that finite modules are isomorphic if and only if they have the same cardinality. The counterexample I'm trying to use is
$$
\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z \ncong \mathbb Z/n^2 \mathbb Z
$$
as $\mathbb Z/n^2\mathbb Z$-modules. However I'm having difficulty showing they aren't isomorphic.

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb{Z}_{n^2}$ is a cyclic group, but $\mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_n$ is not.

Comment: The additive orders of every element on the left side is a divisor of $n$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Think about the "order" of elements. In other words, there is some $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ that annihilates every element in the LHS, but doesn't annihilate the RHS.

Comment: If you want to talk about "some" $n$, probably better not to re-use the name of the actual value. :)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Fair enough. Edited.

Comment: I see, alternatively would it be sufficient to say there's an element of order $n^2$ on RHS and not LHS?

Comment: @TheProblem Provided by order you mean the "smallest" nonzero integer annihilating someone (the definition is more natural in terms of ideals, since not every ring has an order). Of course, also $n^2$ also annihilates the LHS.

Comment: Ah right, that clears things up. Thank you

Comment: @AreaMan The question isn't about rings, though, it is about modules, and "order" makes sense in a module as additive order (since every module is also an abelian group.) You don't have to think about annihilators that way...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews True. I had in mind the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ action when talking about orders and annihilation, but you are correct that every module (over a unital ring) is also a $\mathbb{Z}$ module.